# POJO класс и некоторые проблемы сериализации

Tags: android, retrofit, pojo

Разрабатываю футбольное приложение с результатами матчей, положением команд в чемпионатах и прочим.
Получаю данные JSON (через retrofit).
При сериализации использую POJO класс где есть, к примеру, поле

```
@SerializedName("position")
@Expose
private Integer position;
```

Проблема в том, что некоторые названия типовых составляющих JSON ответа отличаются в зависимости от задаваемых при запросе параметров. Проще говоря: при запросе таблицы чемпионатов какой-либо страны, положение команды в таблице обозначено как position, но при запросе таблиц лиги чемпионов или лиги европы вместо position приходят данные с именем rank; и так еще несколько полей по аналогии. То есть смысл данных для класса один и тот-же но имена разные. Не хочется городить еще один класс под все это, тем более это повлечет еще кучу избыточного кода. Есть ли какой способ обойти эту проблему проще?

Comment: Происходит именно замена названия? Или в первом случае присутствует нужное значение rank и position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно документации Gson, с помощью аннотации [@SerializedName](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)  можно задавать несколько альтернативных имён:

```
  @SerializedName(value="position", alternate={"rank"})
  @Expose
  private Integer position;
```

Если конечно в json будет приходить одно имя, а не оба сразу

Comment: а вот это уже интересно, спасибо, проверю

Answer (score 2):

Сделай класс, получающий данные и проверяй какой именно это случай. Перепиши одно поле в соответствии с выбранным тобой (уже реализованным) шаблоном и пользуйся сериализацией через этот фильтр.

Comment: А можно подробней (как можно проверить какой случай)?

Comment: Проверку на наличие параметра rank в тексте ответа сервера. Если есть то находишь в тексте ответа и вырезаешь из ответа 4 символа с позиции найденного слова, и вставляешь на эту же позицию position и отправляешь данные в свой класс.

Answer (score 1):

В класс добавить оба поля. Если это примитивы, то инициализировать из невалидным для объекта значением. Например не может быть позиции -1. Если это объекты, то они и так будут null.

Создать геттер для позиции и в нем проверять поля на валидность значения, возвращать валидное. Сработает только если оба поля взаимозаменяемые и в json присутствует только один из них.

```
 int position = -1;
 int rank = -1;

 int getPosition(){
      if(position != -1)
           return position;
      else
           return rank;
 }
```

Единственное ограничение - везде где нужна позиция придется использовать геттер.

Comment: Имхо, не очень красивый вариант, ибо объект будет содержать кучу полей, некоторые из которых будут не использоваться. Лучше написать свой десериализатор.

Comment: @post_zeew не спорю, вопрос в том сколько таких полей. Автор написал про одно поле, если это так, то мой вариант проще и короче. Если таких полей много, тут ваш вариант отлично подойдет.

Comment: Виктор, спасибо за ответ. Думаю это вполне рабочий вариант (были догадки так сделать), но, согласен с @post_zeew, так как поле такое не одно